# Get Context.User.Identity from signalr hub in blazor server app (.NET 7)

Tags: blazor, signalr, identity, .net-7.0, hub

I would like to understand why `Context.User.Identity.Name` is `null` and why `Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `false` inside a signalr Hub in the `onConnectedAsync` method? Msdn says:

"SignalR can be used with ASP.NET Core authentication to associate a user with each connection...

In a browser-based app, cookie authentication allows existing user credentials to automatically flow to SignalR connections. When using the browser client, no extra configuration is needed. If the user is logged in to an app, the SignalR connection automatically inherits this authentication."

Project code available here :

[https://github.com/nl20121974/CC](https://github.com/nl20121974/CC.git)

Précision : in this case, user was previously authenticated with the standard authentication form against membership individual accounts (database username + password) from the blazor app. I started with the Microsoft blazor chat sample. This one :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app

The user logs in first from the authentication form with credentials (username + password) from database (.net membership) and goes to the chat page where the user name is automatically sent to chat hub when the "Chat" button is clicked.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to fill a connected users list from signalr hub directly

I searched on Msdn blazor and signalr documentation and Googled a lot.

Comment: Because the web app allows anonymous authentication and the users aren't authenticated. There are no connected users to list, just nameless connections

Comment: I edited my post : in this case, user was previously authenticated with the standard authenticatiion form from the blazor app. I started with the Microsoft blazor chat sample.

Comment: We can't guess how the web app and specifically authentication was configured. Not even what sample was used. The [Azure SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app) sample demonstrates the Azure SignalR service and doedn't use authentication either. The username is entered manually by the user

Comment: The [SignalR with Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server) sample doesn't use authentication either. Once again the username is entered manually

Comment: I update my post  : This one : 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-tutorial-build-blazor-server-chat-app

The user logs in first from the authenticatiion form and goes to the chat page where the user name is automatically sent to chat hub when the "Chat" button is clicked.

Comment: The username is entered manually by the user in the `chatroom` page, stored in the `_username` parameter. That's the older Azure SignalR example, the [SignalR with Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server) example uses less code to do the same things *but* also requires manual entry.

Comment: Check the  [Secure ASP.NET Core Blazor Server apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and SignalR's [Authentication and Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0) documentation. When you create a new Blazor Server app you can specify the authentication mechanism: Windows, Microsoft Identity (essentially Azure AD) or Individual Accounts(local database storage). The template will create wrap the main App component in an `AuthorizeRouteView` automatically

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated my post. Code sample available here :

https://github.com/nl20121974/CC

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is when you hook the request in your hub, there is no JWT token. (If you use JWT token also)

(I'm in .NET 6)

So you need to create a PostConfigureOptions class:

```
public class ConfigureJwtBearerOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
{
    public void PostConfigure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        var originalOnMessageReceived = options.Events.OnMessageReceived;
        options.Events.OnMessageReceived = async context =>
        {
            await originalOnMessageReceived(context);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Token))
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                    path.StartsWithSegments("/hub"))
                {
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

in you Program.cs :

```
services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>());
```

Everything is detailled here : [SignalR authentication & authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

I also created a AppClaimsPrincipalFactory. But I'm not sure you would need this:

```
public class AppClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
{
    public AppClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    { 

    }

    public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName))
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] {new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName)});
            
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.LastName))
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName)});

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Email))
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email) });

        return principal;
    }
}



services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

Comment: Hi bisjob, i updated my post, i am not using token but individual account from .net membeeship

Comment: Can you show us the `ConfigureServices()` method in your Startup.cs ?

Comment: Will dit it this evening, i updated my post this morning.  The project code is  here : https://github.com/nl20121974/CC

Comment: It seems you need to add your authCookie in the hubConnection : `_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(_hubUrl, o => o.Cookies = authCookie).Build();`. On Blazor wasm, I need provide a TokenProvider using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider` (Because I have JWT auth)

Comment: No it's written in msdn for my case : SignalR can be used with ASP.NET Core authentication to associate a user with each connection. In a browser-based app, cookie authentication allows existing user credentials to automatically flow to SignalR connections. When using the browser client, no extra configuration is needed. If the user is logged in to an app, the SignalR connection automatically inherits this authentication.

Comment: Oh ok. I don't have much experience with cookies. I saw in you program.cs that you don't add Authentication in the services `services.AddAuthentication()`, you only set `app.UseAuthorization();`. Maybe you can try to add this. It will let you change options for cookies. But as you are using the default autentication system, I'm not sure it's necessary. Sorry to not help you as much as I thought I could. 
If you find the reason you don't have your IdentityClaim in your hub, can you post it here ? I'm curious to know why too

Answer (score -1):

Get username in blazor .Net6 .Net8

in page:

```
    @using BlazorApp1.Data
    @using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
    @inject AuthenticationStateProvider GetAuthenticationStateAsync

@email


@code{
string email;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authstate = await GetAuthenticationStateAsync.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authstate.User;
        var name = user.Identity.Name;
        email = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not from client but from the signalr hub, to full a list of connected users in the chat hub

Comment: The question is about getting the username from HttpContext in a SignalR Hub, Not about getting the username from AuthenticationStateProvider in a Blazor component.